# using coward vs. cowardly in a sentence

Tags: attributive-nouns, compound-nouns

He was a coward xyz soldier.

He was a cowardly xyz soldier.

here xyz is the adj. 'of a particular country'..

which of the two is correct and why?

In addition to the question above.. can't a coward man be used as a compound noun, like a ghost story.. a war hero.. ???

Comment: Related question on ELU: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/44469/241163

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question because you've added that bit about compound nouns.

After all, there are some compound nouns that indeed use the word *soldier*, such as:

- mercenary soldier
- citizen soldier

However, *coward soldier* isn't a valid compound noun, and therefore you would want to use the form with the adjective: *cowardly soldier*.

The tricky part is explaining why. My first guess was:

**We don't usually form compound nouns with modifiers that are easily converted into adjectives.**

That might explain your first example compound, *war hero.* It's difficult to change *war* into an adjective. (Sure, there's the adjective *warlike*, but that has a different meaning and it would change the meaning of the compound lexeme.)

But then I thought about your second example: *ghost story*. If a "ghost story" is a story about a ghost (and "ghostly story" is not), then why couldn't a "coward soldier" be a soldier who behaved like a coward, rather than "cowardly soldier"? I don't really have a good answer to that, and I'm not sure there is one. As one blogger wrote:

> As Ronald Carter and Michael McCarthy put it in "Cambridge Grammar of English," the compound noun structure is "extremely varied in the types of meaning relations it can indicate," from what the object is for *like waste-paper basket* to what something is made of like *woodpile* or *metal slab*, how something works like a *convection oven* to what someone does like a *language teacher*.
>
> As a result, usage rules for everything from punctuation to capitalization can be confusing, especially for new English grammar learners.
>
> <sup>([Source](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-compound-noun-1689892))</sup>

Sometimes there's simply not an easy rule to explain the way things are the way that they are, and work the way that they do.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's modifying the noun phrase "xyz soldier", the word should be an adjective. "Coward" is a noun, and therefore wold be unidiomatic as a modifier for another noun.

Comment: what about.. ghost story, which is a compound noun. Can't we consider a coward man, a compound noun. where coward and man are both nouns. so  a coward man??

Answer (score 0):

*Coward* is a noun.  It means someone or something that won't do something due to fear.

*Cowardly* is an adjective.  A *cowardly X* behaves like a coward.

So in this case you want to say *cowardly*.